# proof related to jump relation in double-layer potential

Tags: partial-differential-equations, potential-theory

Assume $D \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a bounded and open domain with  $C^{2}$ boundary. Let $x \in \partial D$ and $r>0$. Define
\begin{align*}
  C_{r} := D \cap \partial B( x,r)  \text{ and } \overline{C_{r}}:= \{y \in \partial B( x,r ): y \cdot \nu( y )<0 \} 
.\end{align*}
WLOG, we may ssume that $x=0$ and the normal derivative $n( x ) $ at  $x$ is given by  $( 0, \ldots ,0 ,-1 ) $. The goal is to show that
\begin{align*}
 \int_{C_{r}} d S_{y} =  \int_{\overline{C_r}} dS_{y} + O( r^{n} ) 
.\end{align*}

This is a proof related to Gauss lemma. https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/potential.pdf (page 8, Claim 3).

I think the idea is when $r$ approaches $0$, $\overline{C_r}$  approaches the half circle of $\partial B(x,r)$. I am a bit lost in first paragraph of the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the notation from:
https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/potential.pdf

They are arguing that surface area of $C_{\epsilon} \setminus \tilde{C_{\epsilon}}$ is bounded by surface area of a strip on the surface of $B(x,\epsilon)$ and hence can be bounded by area of a rectangle along the surface of $B(x,\epsilon)$ where base length is the circumference of the $B(x,\epsilon)$ and hence is the volume of a $n-2$ dimensional sphere of radius $\epsilon$ and hence $O(\epsilon^{n-2})$.
Now height of the strip or rectangle is obtained as follows. The boundary $\Omega$ is a $C^2$ boundary and hence is defined by $\partial \Omega \cap B(x,\epsilon) = \{(y_1,...,y_{n-1},y_n) : y_n = f(y_1,...,y_{n-1})\}$. This is by definition.

Now assume $x = 0$ is the origin and hence the height is the value of $y_n$ at distance $\epsilon$ from origin (on the surface of $B(x,\epsilon)$) and $y_n$ is bounded by $f(y_1,...,y_{n-1})$ evaluated with $(y_1,...,y_{n-1})$ on the
$n-1$ dimensional sphere of $B(x,\epsilon)$ which is passing through $x$ and lies in $v(x).y =0$ i.e., $y_n =0$. Since $y_n > 0$ (by the fact $y.v(x) < 0$), we have $|y_n| \leq |f(y_1,...,y_{n-1})|$. Now apply Taylor series to $n-1$ variable function $f$ and write $$f(y_1,...,y_{n-1}) = f(0)+\nabla f(0) (y_1,...,y_{n-1})^T$$ $$+(y_1,...,y_{n-1}) Hessian(f(\gamma)) (y_1,...,y_{n-1})^T$$. Since $Hessian(f(\gamma))$ is bounded on a compact set, we have $$|f(y_1,...,y_{n-1})| \leq |f(0)| + |\nabla f(0)| |(y_1,...,y_{n-1})| $$ $$+ \sup_{y_1,..,y_{n-1}: |(y_1,...,y_{n-1})| \leq \epsilon} |Hessian f(y)| \times |(y_1,..y_{n-1})|^2 \leq C \epsilon^2$$

This is because they assumed $f(0) = \nabla f(0) = 0$ and $Hessian(f)|_{y_1,y_2,...,y_{n-1}=0}$ is full rank.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I am still a bit confused with the part related to $O(\epsilon^{n-2})$. For example, when $n=2$, $C_{\epsilon}-\tilde{C_{\epsilon}}$ will be two pieces of curves.  The surface area will just be the length of two curves.  How does it related to the height and base length?

Comment: For $n=2$, we have $0$-dimensional circumference and the measure is point measure. So base has measure $1$ (since one point base). you also have $\epsilon^{n-2} = \epsilon^{2-2} = 1$. In this case, the length of pieces of curve is equal to height and hence height times base since base is of trivial unit measure corresponding to 0-dimensional lebesgue measure which is a point measure.

Comment: Sorry, would you mind explaining what are the height and base? I was looking at the figure in that lecture note. The difference of $\int_{C_{\epsilon} -\tilde{C_{\epsilon}}} 1 d S_y$  is just the arc length of two pieces on the circle. I must have some misunderstandings of the materials.

Comment: $n=2$ is the simplest case. Now take $n=3$, base is the circumference of the circle along the 3 D sphere equator and height is the length of the curve equivalent. For $n=2$ circumference of the circle reduces to a point which has point measure $1$. Think in 3 dimensions, it will be clear